# Offset then addclass to div

Tags: jquery, class, action, offset

My question is about finding the y position of the browser using .offset()
and at one point I want to add class to my div
I want to create something like [yourkarma.com](http://yourkarma.com) (look at WHAT IS POWERING IT section)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function (event) {
    // what the y position of the scroll is
    var z = '150';
    var x = $('#thisdiv').offset().top - z;
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();

    // whether that's below the form
    if (y >= x) {
      // if so, ad the fixed class
      $('#thisdiv').addClass('red');
    }
  });
})
```

Am I on the right way?
I feel like using z=150 and minus it to X is kind of cheap way.
Is there anyway to make a better one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not cheap but maybe a more clearer and efficient way is:

```
var $thisdiv = $('#thisdiv');
var thisdiv_top = $thisdiv.offset().top - 150;
var thisdiv_flag = false;

$(window).scroll(function (event) {
    if(thisdiv_flag) return;

    // what the y position of the scroll is
    var y = $(window).scrollTop();

    // whether that's below the form
    if (y >= thisdiv_top) {
        // if so, ad the fixed class
        $thisdiv.addClass('red');
        thisdiv_flag = true;
    }
});
```

I'm not exactly sure why the -150. I guess so it would trigger a little sooner before the element is in view. But this code is a little more efficient. It caches the jQuery object for the div and sets a flag so the event does not fire again. It also keeps from having to do the same offset calculation every time the user scrolls.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello,
Thanks for the answer, that if (false) kind of boolean? I never seen it before.

Yes, without 150, I must wait the top of the browser touch that element itself.

Comment: And why this is better? I'm pretty sure my code prevent the event fire twice, doesn't it?

Comment: Add `console.log('test');` under `$('#thisdiv').addClass('red');` in your original code and you will see that it will execute multiple times as you scroll up and down. Your code should work however it isn't as efficient because you should cache the jQuery object of the div and you don't need to calculate the div offset every time the user scrolls because it is the same value every time.

Comment: thanks, that make sense!
any tips for me? so I will never repeat the same mistake again.
the mistake I mean here is my code fired every time

Comment: Just follow my example. You need to have a flag outside the scope of the event so it will be persistent with each fired event. When the event fires just set the flag to `true`. Please vote up my answer if it helps you. You are welcome.